# awk if - statements after the if

Tags: awk

Could you help me with the following syntax error? When I have one statement after the “if” , the program works. But when I want two statements after an “if” , I get errors.
Thanks,
Carl.

```
BEGIN { FS = “,” }
{ if ( $2 == “” && ( $6 == “Install” || $6 == “Add” || $6 == “New”) )
{
print $1″,”$2″,”$3″,”$4″,”$5″,”$6″,”$7″,”$8″,”$9 > “Email_Asset_Add” ;
print “$8″,”$9 > “Email_Asset_Add_Mitul” ;
}
else if ( $2 == “” && ( $6 == “Change” || $6 == “Update” || $6 == “Existing”) )
{
print $1″,”$2″,”$3″,”$4″,”$5″,”$6″,”$7″,”$8″,”$9 > “Email_Asset_Update” ;
print “$8″,”$9 > “Email_Asset_Update_Mitul” ;
}
}
```

awk -f awk_program test_email
awk: newline in string near line 23
awk: newline in string near line 28

Comment: I think your problem is here print $1″: it's print "$1″. And it's not the only not closed string, but I don't know AWK so I don't know if it's correct to have just one quote.

Comment: That was it  ( along with the missing " after the $9's ) .  Thank you!

Comment: Your quoting is inconsistent, and `print` wants a comma separated list. Try `print $1, ",", $2, ",", ...` or `printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3` instead.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I want to print $1 then a "," then $2 and then a "," and so on. I want to print each field with a comma in between.

Comment: Fixed. Once I adjusted my comma's ( I had some extra ones ) the program now works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since your block just contains two `if` conditions, why not use [the conditions as awk patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Expression-Patterns)?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend simplifying your code using `printf()`.

For example, this:

```
print $1”,”$2”,”$3”,”$4”,”$5”,”$6”,”$7”,”$8”,”$9 > “Email_Asset_Add” ;
```

could become this:

```
printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9) > “Email_Asset_Add”;
```

Much easier to see where things are that way.

In fact, the whole thing could do with a bit of refactoring:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = “,”;
}

{
  if ( $2 == “” && ( $6 == “Install” || $6 == “Add” || $6 == “New”) ) {
    output="Email_Asset_Add";
  } else
  if ( $2 == “” && ( $6 == “Change” || $6 == “Update” || $6 == “Existing”) ) {
    output="Email_Asset_Update";
  } else {
    next;
  }
  printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9) > output;
  printf("%s,%s\n", $8,$9); > “Email_Asset_Update_Mitul” ;
}
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment?  How is this answer incorrect or misleading?